# A Terminal Issue Need Someone From VSCode core team to indicate me to the right code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a pull request to solve a problem related to integrated terminal environment variable. The feature link can be found through [this link #4568](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4568). The problem behavior descriptions can be found in [this link #4434](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4434). In this link, I proposed a workaround. But I still want to fix this problem.

Through my own observation, I found the root cause may be: after some steps, somewhere during the create terminal process, the actual environment variable values(specific to PATH) has been reordered/changed. Maybe it is being processed for remove duplication.

I download the vscode codebase(1.33) and follow the debugging until method `createProcess` in source file `src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/electron-browser/terminalProcessManager.ts`. What I have found is: even after the terminal instance has been created, the `env.PATH` in the main process has **NOT** been changed. For ptyProcess, the constructor takes options(which contains env) as input, but I cannot find any env related property in created ptyProcess. And after the terminal instance created, the debugging ends, integrated terminal appears in the workbench. I get lost after terminal instance created, can someone from the core team or used to working on integrated terminal module indicate me to the right place in the codebase so I can try to solve the issue? There is not enough documents on internet or comments in the source code can help me find/locate the environments changing during/after the terminal instance creation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it related to internal implementation details of the application in question and will likely be stale in a couple of months anyway.

Comment: I second that. If anyone is interested in the topic, you can follow this issue on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/70248

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too and after reading your github issue I decided to mess about with my $HOME/.bashxxxx files and see what works. I needed to solve the similar problem but with yarn. It was possible to launch it from any terminal bash, zsh I had. But not from vscode. I am working with MacOs

I tried various files with the following addition

> PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/:$PATH

What I found was that adding to $HOME/.bashrc and relaunching vscode didn't fix the problem. I was still unable to run yarn.

Adding to $HOME/.bash_profile did work and I was able to run yarn in vscode

I was never able to find out how homebrew updates the path and what files it modifies. But this was the quickest way to solve my problem and I can live with any duplicate paths. I just wanted to let people know cause I wasted three hours on this. It wasn't worth it.